# Where to get the configuration? (Mail Client)

Tags: email, configuration, local

I just purchased a domain name few weeks ago,
and then i registered my domain into Windows Live Admin ( domain.live.com )
because from that Windows Live, I could manage 
several email accounts. And I did. now every time I 
want to write email / receive email i just go to mail.live.com
and login depend on the email accounts I just made there.

Then I tried to install Opera Mail, or even Thunderbird
in my Computer (laptop).

There are several configuration I confused.
What should I type into the incoming and outcoming server ? Imap / Pop? Which port?

I dunno.... 
Confused.

Because WHen I try to use thee details:

> IMAP Server: as imap.charter.net  SMPT Server: as smpt.charter.net

It doesnt work.

Then I tried to use

> mail.mydomain.com

for both incoming & outgoing server.

And it is also doesnt work.

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the outlook.com server, not your own domain:

```
Incoming mail server - imap-mail.outlook.com
Incoming mail server port - 993 (SSL)
Outgoing (SMTP) mail server - smtp-mail.outlook.com
Outgoing (SMTP) mail server port - 587 (SSL/TLS)
Outgoing server (SMTP) authentication - same settings as your incoming mail server
```